# Geoserver Authentication with OAuth2

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, geoserver

I am attempting to sync up Geoserver with Google's OAuth2 authentication system. I have been following Geoserver's [OAuth Documentation](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/community/oauth2/index.html) with the 2.12 nightly build but the option to set up the authentication does not seem to be available from the GUI. I assumed the module was packaged with the build but I don't see the configuration. Is there a specific directory I can check to be sure that I have the module locally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [OAuth module](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/community/oauth2/index.html) is a [community module](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/community/index.html) which means it is not included in the released build, you need to fetch the jars from the [nightly build server](https://build.geoserver.org/geoserver/2.12.x/community-latest/).

I believe you will need:

```
geoserver-2.12-SNAPSHOT-authkey-plugin.zip
```

and one (or more) of

```
geoserver-2.12-SNAPSHOT-sec-oauth2-geonode-plugin.zip
geoserver-2.12-SNAPSHOT-sec-oauth2-github-plugin.zip
geoserver-2.12-SNAPSHOT-sec-oauth2-google-plugin.zip
```